# Problems with hiding and showing element with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with hiding some of my content. I am very new to coding, i started with coding for a week ago. Until now i have learned html, the most inportaint css, and how to use bootstrap 4. My problem is I want to hide some content. I have searched around on the web for hours, and the only ting i found useful was the d-none and d-sm-block and all the other hide and show tags. I tried it several places in my code without any luck, so hope anyone can help.
I want the search bar, log in and register button on small screens to disappear, and then a small dropdown menu shows up instead(only on the small screens). In the dropdown menu i want to have the log in an register button. I know i didn't use boopstrap as navbar at the top, but thats beacause I hadn't learn it yet, and i didn't want to change it since I liked the size on the buttons.
Hope anyone can help.

The top of my html code.(The hotpink buttons are bigger in my real code since I have other text in it)

```
<head>
    <title>hello world</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../test_sublime/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link href="test1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h2><em><u>Header</u></em>.no</h2>
        <nav class="headnav">
            <ul>
                <li class="hotpink"><a class="b_link" href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li class="hotpink"><a class="b_link" href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li class="hotpink"><a class="b_link" href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li class="hotpink"><a class="b_link" href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li class="hotpink"><a class="b_link" href="#">Test</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>      
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="../test_sublime/logg in.html" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Logg In</a>
            <a href="../test_sublime/registrer.html" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Register</a>
        <!--This is the search bar I want to hide when the screen is small-->
        </div>
            <form class="form-inline my-lg sok">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 msok" type="search" placeholder="Søk" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 msok" type="submit">Søk</button>
            </form>
        <!--I want this dropdown menu to show up when the screen is small-->
        <div class="dropdown-menu d-block d-sm-none" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../test_sublime/logg in.html">Logg Inn</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="../test_sublime/registrer.html">Register Deg</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        </div>
    </header>

        ...

    <footer>
        ...
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script scr="../test_sublime/jQuery/jquery.js"><\/script>');</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../test_sublime/js/test.js"></script>
    <script src="test_sublime/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Parts of my css

```
body {
background: pink;
margin-left: 12px;
margin-right: 12px;
margin-top: 10px;
}

h2 {
display:inline;
background: mediumvioletred;
padding: 20px 40px 7px 40px;
margin: 0px 5px 40px -15px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

ul {
display: inline;
margin: 0px 0px 0px -38px
}

.sok {
display: inline-block;
float: right;
margin-right: 35px;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.msok {
margin-top: 0px;
}

.btn-group { 
padding: 0px 10px 0px -10px
display: inline;
float: right;
margin-top: 10px;
}

nav.headnav {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Is it any ways to fix it with bootstrap, or do i have to use JavaSript or something else?
(Sorry for the colors)

Comment: I would suggest you use bootstrap. Why reinvent the wheel? The size of your buttons can be tailored using css and bootstrap together.

Comment: hiding elements is simply a matter of styling, simplest being setting `display:none` via style attribute or css.  Bootstrap is intended to style visual (non-hidden) elements, or soon to be visual as in the case with nav menus and such. So while it's a good idea to become familiar with Bootstrap, I don't think it's an answer to your "hiding an element" issue

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query in your css

`@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    form.sok {
    display: none;
    }`

You can hide the elements based on screen size.
[Bootstrap Responsive Break Points](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem using navbar class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-        toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-    expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">yourbrand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"     role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        <span class="btn input-group-addon">Search</span>
                </div>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a href="../test_sublime/logg in.html" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Logg In</a>
                <a href="../test_sublime/registrer.html" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Register</a>
            </div>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```